# Unable to attach to application WebDev.WebServer40.exe Visual Studio has insufficient privileges

Tags: asp.net

Unable to attach to application WebDev.WebServer40.exe Visual Studio has insufficient priveleges to debug this process.

I am getting the following error when trying to debug a simple new asp.net web application.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to run the VS as the administrator (right-click the icon and select the optiin from the os shell context menu).

Comment: I do not have the option to select Run as Administrator in Windows 2003 Server however I tried to run VS under a user account who is in the Administrators group in Windows 2003 Server OS but still got the same error message.

Comment: You have. Shift + right click the shortcut.

Comment: I tried Shift + Right click but I still don't see the Run as Administrator option. I only see Run as and when I click on it this is the prompt I get: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/images/RunAsRestricted.png I have tried unchecking the Run this program with restricted access.

Comment: Select an administrator account and provide credentials.

Comment: The current user logged in is an administrator account.

Comment: I know, you wrote this. And it doesn't matter, unless you explicitely "Run as ..." an administrator account, the UAC could possibly restrict priviledges when you just execute applications as current logged user.

Comment: Kind of weird but I installed Visual Studio SP 1 and I don't get that same error again. Now when I try to build a project I get Error  Could not write to output file 'C:\...\obj\Debug\ReferencedDll.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '  I get the same error for a bunch of dlls. I have tried deleting the obj folder but still get the same error.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am facing same issue but not able to solve it with running VS as Administrator .. would you please help me

Answer (score 1):

I closed visual studio and then killed all visual studio processes. After this I restarted visual studio and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you find more than one 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE'  in  customize notification area right click and close it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just reboot the machine error will sovle.